# Gaussian vectors and covariance matrix.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

The following is a part of a question I was given in stochastic processes course. It goes like this - I am given a series of gaussian **iid** random variables $\{V_i\}_{i=1}^N$ , the variable $X_0 \sim N[0,\sigma^2]$ which is statistically independent in  $\{V_i\}_{i=1}^N$ , $\beta\neq 0 $ which is a deterministic parameter and the following recursive formula which defines a group of random variables : $X_{i+1}=\beta X_i+V_i$ .  Now , in the last part we are told that $ \{X_i\}_{i=0}^N $ are identically distributed with $\mu=0, \sigma^2$ and we need to determine the i,j  component of the 2nd moment matrix (which is defined by $E[\underline{X}\cdot \underline{X}^T]$). My guess is since $\mu=0$ then this is actually the covariance matrix of the vector $\underline{X}$ ,and since all components are identically distributed then each element at index ij of the matrix represents $\text{Cov}[X_i,X_j]=\text{Var}[X_i]=\sigma^2$ . Am I right or am I totally missing something? Thanks for the help, Mark.

Comment: That $S$ and $T$ are identically distributed does not imply that $\mathrm{Cov}(S,T)=\mathrm{Var}(S)$. // The question is not solvable without some hypothesis on the joint distribution of $(V_i)$. Is it i.i.d.?

Comment: I just came up with an idea that if we try to generally calculate 
$\text{Cov}[X_i,X_j]$ then following the recursive relation and assuming i<j we get : $\text{Cov}[X_i,X_j]=\text{Cov}[X_i,\beta X_{j-1}+V_{j-1}]=\text{Cov}[X_i,\beta^2 X_{j-2}+\beta V_{j-2}]=...=\text{Cov}[X_i,\beta^{j-i} X_i+\beta^{j-i-1} V_i]=\beta^{j-i} \text{Var}[X_i]+\beta^{j-i-1}\underbrace{\text{Cov}[X_i,V_i]}_{=0}=\beta^{j-i} \sigma^2 $

Comment: for i>j we should get : $\beta^{i-j}\sigma^2$ and i=j simply $\sigma^2$

Comment: I'd love to hear feedback + still anticipating to hear your idea.

Comment: Here is my feedback: why not **signaling** the crucial modification you brought to your question just after I posted my first comment?

Comment: My bad, I'm somewhat new to this forum and still get lost with editing the text here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results follow from the following identities, using the structure of the process $(V_i)$. Note that
$$X_i=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\beta^{n-1}V_{i-n}
$$
hence
$$
\mathrm{var}(X)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\beta^{2(n-1)}\mathrm{var}(V)=\frac{\mathrm{var}(V)}{1-\beta^2}$$
and that, for every $j\geqslant0$,
$$X_i=\beta^jX_{i-j}+\sum_{n=1}^j\beta^{n-1}V_{i-n}
$$
hence
$$
\mathrm{cov}(X_i,X_{i-j})=\beta^j\mathrm{var}(X).
$$